# Check Box control is not visible. How to make it visible

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, radio-button

I can't see checkboxes and radiobuttons in my web page. I do not understand where I make mistake. In my first template there is no problem. However after changing template there are problems with checkboxes and radiobuttons.

Here is the code :

```
<div class="grid_12">
    <div class="box round first fullpage" style="height: 330px">
        <h2>E-mail Ayarları</h2>
        <div class="block">
            <asp:button id="btn_mail_ekle" runat="server" text="Ekle" cssclass="btn btn-small" onclick="btn_mail_ekle_Click" />
            <div class="gvclass">
                <p>
                    <span>
                        <asp:gridview runat="server" id="GridView4" cellpadding="4"
                            width="100%" rowstyle-wrap="True"
                            rowstyle-height="30px" pagesize="20" emptydatatext="Görüntülenecek Öğe Bulunmamaktadır....."
                            gridlines="Horizontal" horizontalalign="Left"
                            onrowcancelingedit="GridView4_RowCancelingEdit"
                            onrowediting="GridView4_RowEditing" onrowupdating="GridView4_RowUpdating">
                            <RowStyle BackColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="true" />
                            <Columns>
                               <asp:CommandField CancelText="İptal" EditText="Düzenle" ShowEditButton="True" UpdateText="Güncelle" ButtonType="Link" ItemStyle-ForeColor="#008f0d">
                                    <ItemStyle ForeColor="#008F0D"></ItemStyle>
                               </asp:CommandField>
                               <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Enabled="False" ID="CheckBox1">
                                        </asp:CheckBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Enabled="False">
                                        </asp:CheckBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                               <asp:TemplateField>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Enabled="False">
                                        </asp:CheckBox>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <HeaderTemplate>
                                    </HeaderTemplate>
                               </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#f2f2f5" Height="30px" />
                            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" CssClass="tablesorter" Wrap="true" ForeColor="#b94309" />
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        </asp:gridview>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Generated Html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="ctl00_Head1"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>
    BCS Acil Uyarı Sistemleri
</title><link id="ctl00_Link1" rel="icon" href="images/sirket_logo.jpg" type="image/ico" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" media="screen" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/text.css" media="screen" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.css" media="screen" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" media="screen" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/nav.css" media="screen" />
    <!--[if IE 6]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie6.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->
    <link href="css/fancy-button/fancy-button.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!--Jquery UI CSS-->
    <link href="css/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="uyari_mesajlari.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- BEGIN: load jquery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.effects.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.effects.slide.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END: load jquery -->
    <!--jQuery Date Picker-->
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.widget.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.progressbar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery dialog related-->
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.mouse.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.draggable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.position.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.resizable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.dialog.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.effects.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.effects.blind.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.effects.explode.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- jQuery dialog end here-->
    <script src="js/jquery-ui/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--Fancy Button-->
    <script src="js/fancy-button/fancy-button.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/setup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Load TinyMCE -->
    <script src="js/tiny-mce/jquery.tinymce.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            setupTinyMCE();
            setupProgressbar('progress-bar');
            setDatePicker('date-picker');
            setupDialogBox('dialog', 'opener');
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').fancybutton();
            $('input[type="radio"]').fancybutton();
        });
    </script>
    <!-- /TinyMCE -->
    <style type="text/css">
        #progress-bar
        {
            width: 400px;
        }
    </style>
   <style type="text/css">
   @font-face {
    font-family: 'allerregular';
    src: url('aller_rg-webfont.eot');
    src: url('aller_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('aller_rg-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('aller_rg-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('aller_rg-webfont.svg#allerregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="emailayarlari.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebResource.axd?d=yJIFJSsFhN9bXVMtwTWZ9tox5KoRRyadljm7eI8i6oRKK9oDUTFQGzg_fFFeTxGMjKwHAVVAalwU0CPBdixzJ7ubiq2_qArXVFlOZTfOzb01&amp;t=634897507112455790" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var __cultureInfo = {"name":"tr-TR","numberFormat":{"CurrencyDecimalDigits":2,"CurrencyDecimalSeparator":",","IsReadOnly":true,"CurrencyGroupSizes":[3],"NumberGroupSizes":[3],"PercentGroupSizes":[3],"CurrencyGroupSeparator":".","CurrencySymbol":"₺","NaNSymbol":"NaN","CurrencyNegativePattern":8,"NumberNegativePattern":1,"PercentPositivePattern":2,"PercentNegativePattern":2,"NegativeInfinitySymbol":"-Sonsuz","NegativeSign":"-","NumberDecimalDigits":2,"NumberDecimalSeparator":",","NumberGroupSeparator":".","CurrencyPositivePattern":3,"PositiveInfinitySymbol":"Sonsuz","PositiveSign":"+","PercentDecimalDigits":2,"PercentDecimalSeparator":",","PercentGroupSeparator":".","PercentSymbol":"%","PerMilleSymbol":"‰","NativeDigits":["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"],"DigitSubstitution":1},"dateTimeFormat":{"AMDesignator":"","Calendar":{"MinSupportedDateTime":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","MaxSupportedDateTime":"\/Date(253402293599999)\/","AlgorithmType":1,"CalendarType":1,"Eras":[1],"TwoDigitYearMax":2029,"IsReadOnly":true},"DateSeparator":".","FirstDayOfWeek":1,"CalendarWeekRule":0,"FullDateTimePattern":"d MMMM yyyy dddd HH:mm:ss","LongDatePattern":"d MMMM yyyy dddd","LongTimePattern":"HH:mm:ss","MonthDayPattern":"d MMMM","PMDesignator":"","RFC1123Pattern":"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss \u0027GMT\u0027","ShortDatePattern":"d.M.yyyy","ShortTimePattern":"HH:mm","SortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd\u0027T\u0027HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss","TimeSeparator":":","UniversalSortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy\u0027-\u0027MM\u0027-\u0027dd HH\u0027:\u0027mm\u0027:\u0027ss\u0027Z\u0027","YearMonthPattern":"MMMM yyyy","AbbreviatedDayNames":["Paz","Pzt","Sal","Çar","Per","Cum","Cmt"],"ShortestDayNames":["Pz","Pt","Sa","Ça","Pe","Cu","Ct"],"DayNames":["Pazar","Pazartesi","Salı","Çarşamba","Perşembe","Cuma","Cumartesi"],"AbbreviatedMonthNames":["Oca","Şub","Mar","Nis","May","Haz","Tem","Ağu","Eyl","Eki","Kas","Ara",""],"MonthNames":["Ocak","Şubat","Mart","Nisan","Mayıs","Haziran","Temmuz","Ağustos","Eylül","Ekim","Kasım","Aralık",""],"IsReadOnly":true,"NativeCalendarName":"Gregoryen Takvim","AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames":["Oca","Şub","Mar","Nis","May","Haz","Tem","Ağu","Eyl","Eki","Kas","Ara",""],"MonthGenitiveNames":["Ocak","Şubat","Mart","Nisan","Mayıs","Haziran","Temmuz","Ağustos","Eylül","Ekim","Kasım","Aralık",""]},"eras":[1,"MS",null,0]};//]]>
</script>

<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=yoQFui4I7K7TNE1XYHnxTFvQK0CsITxXEkVIT0tJ6T6V903Fg7lPRzdYu4NZ8T7aRBSKh7SAY3KRbdTmOikXBX1y2KFvp7AQ22PxnV_FHoU4MkAs5aoqFb0jxg5uftDn0&amp;t=7f16157c" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=evsQDCIZ_UCKfQSF0nBOLhubsUsnpp-rmYbiV0U5aYUvA9ijSIGhnt1mle399YwMY1l74A1hrgtzc4yWji409rHpVyqbslDdb8eOrlZW_6ZLNax8TS8zIBVfHgrkaCnSzNkNaaMVLmYGrK2nQasg6Q2&amp;t=7f16157c" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ctl00$ScriptManager1', 'aspnetForm', [], [], [], 90, 'ctl00');
//]]>
</script>

  <div class="container_12">
        <div class="grid_12 header-repeat">
            <div id="branding">
                <div class="floatleft" style=" color:White">
                   <img id="ctl00_Image1" src="images/kontrol.gif" align="left" style="height:50px;border-width:0px;" /> 

                             </div>
                             <div style=" float:left; padding-left:20px">
 <img id="ctl00_Image7" src="images/bcs.png" align="left" style="height:50px;width:120px;border-width:0px;" />

                             </div>
                             <div style=" float:left; color:White; padding-left:20px; padding-top:20px">
                             <span id="ctl00_Label27">İZMİR DR.SUAT SEREN GÖĞÜS HASTALIKLARI VE CERRAHİSİ EĞİTİM VE ARAŞTIRMA HASTANESİ</span>
                             </div>
                <div class="floatright">
                    <div class="floatleft">
                        <img src="images/img-profile.jpg" alt="Profile Pic" /></div>
                    <div class="floatleft marginleft10">
                    <span class="small grey">Merhaba  <span id="ctl00_lblKullanici">YÖNETİCİ</span>
                    <a id="ctl00_LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$LinkButton1&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Çıkış</a>  
                    </span>
                        <br />
                        <span class="small grey">Son Giriş Tarihi:</span>
                        <br />
                        <span class="small grey"></asp:Label></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
        <div class="grid_12">
            <ul class="nav main">
                <li class="ic-form-style"><a href="#"><span>Müdahale Ekipleri ve Kullanıcılar</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="mudahaleekipleri.aspx">Ekipler ve BCS Kullanıcıları</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="kullanicilar.aspx">Konsültasyon Kullanıcıları</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="klinikler.aspx">Konsültasyon Klinikler</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="ic-grid-tables"><a href="#"><span>Sistem Ayarları</span></a>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="dahilinumaralar.aspx">Dahili Numaralar</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="sistemayarlari.aspx">Sistem Ayarları</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="emailayarlari.aspx">E-mail Ayarları</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="pagerayarlari.aspx">Pager Cihazları</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="mudahalesorulari.aspx">Müdahale Raporu Soruları</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>



         <div class="grid_12" style="min-height:1200px">   


<div style=" padding-top:1%; padding-left:1%; padding-right:1%">

</div>

<div class="grid_12">
            <div class="box round first fullpage">
                 <h2>E-mail Zaman Ayarları</h2>
                 <div class="block">
        <div class="gvclass">
                <p><span>
            <select name="ctl00$icerik$ddl_mail_ayarlari" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$icerik$ddl_mail_ayarlari\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="ctl00_icerik_ddl_mail_ayarlari" class="fontcevir" style="width:60%;">
    <option value="0">Mail g&#246;nderilmesini istemiyorum.</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Her g&#252;n saat 00:01&#39;de aşağıdaki adreslere mail g&#246;nderilmesini istiyorum.</option>
    <option value="2">Her hafta pazartesi g&#252;n&#252; saat 07:00&#39;de aşağıdaki adreslere mail g&#246;nderilmesini istiyorum.</option>
    <option value="3">Her ayın 1. g&#252;n&#252; saat 07:00&#39;de aşağıdaki adreslere mail g&#246;nderilmesini istiyorum.</option>

</select>
        </span>      
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_12">
            <div class="box round first fullpage" style=" height:330px">
                 <h2>E-mail Ayarları</h2>
                 <div class="block">

                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$icerik$btn_mail_ekle" value="Ekle" id="ctl00_icerik_btn_mail_ekle" class="btn btn-small" />
                         <div class="gvclass">
                <p><span>
            <div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" align="Left" rules="rows" border="1" id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr class="tablesorter" align="left" valign="middle" style="color:#B94309;">
            <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">
                       Günlük
                       </th><th scope="col">
                       Haftalık
                       </th><th scope="col">
                       Aylık
                       </th><th scope="col">E-mail Adresi</th><th scope="col">Eklenme Zamanı</th>
        </tr><tr align="left" valign="middle" style="background-color:White;height:30px;">
            <td style="color:#008F0D;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Edit$0&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Düzenle</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Delete$0&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Sil</a></td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl02_CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl02$CheckBox1" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl02_CheckBox2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl02$CheckBox2" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl02_CheckBox3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl02$CheckBox3" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>bilgeugur35@gmail.com</td><td>5.1.2013 09:13:02</td>
        </tr><tr align="left" valign="middle" style="background-color:White;height:30px;">
            <td style="color:#008F0D;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Edit$1&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Düzenle</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Delete$1&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Sil</a></td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl03_CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl03$CheckBox1" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl03_CheckBox2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl03$CheckBox2" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl03_CheckBox3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl03$CheckBox3" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>a@gmail.com</td><td>5.1.2013 09:30:10</td>
        </tr><tr align="left" valign="middle" style="background-color:White;height:30px;">
            <td style="color:#008F0D;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Edit$2&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Düzenle</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Delete$2&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Sil</a></td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl04_CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl04$CheckBox1" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl04_CheckBox2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl04$CheckBox2" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl04_CheckBox3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl04$CheckBox3" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>dfgfdgfdgfdg@gfdgdf.com</td><td>17.1.2013 08:35:40</td>
        </tr><tr align="left" valign="middle" style="background-color:White;height:30px;">
            <td style="color:#008F0D;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Edit$3&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Düzenle</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Delete$3&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Sil</a></td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl05_CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl05$CheckBox1" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl05_CheckBox2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl05$CheckBox2" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl05_CheckBox3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl05$CheckBox3" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>dsfsdfsdqddsfdsf@fd</td><td>5.1.2013 10:09:59</td>
        </tr><tr align="left" valign="middle" style="background-color:White;height:30px;">
            <td style="color:#008F0D;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Edit$4&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Düzenle</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Delete$4&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Sil</a></td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl06_CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl06$CheckBox1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl06_CheckBox2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl06$CheckBox2" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl06_CheckBox3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl06$CheckBox3" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>sfsdfdsfq@gmail.com</td><td>17.1.2013 08:35:31</td>
        </tr><tr align="left" valign="middle" style="background-color:White;height:30px;">
            <td style="color:#008F0D;"><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Edit$5&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Düzenle</a>&nbsp;<a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$icerik$GridView4&#39;,&#39;Delete$5&#39;)" style="color:#008F0D;">Sil</a></td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl07_CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl07$CheckBox1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl07_CheckBox2" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl07$CheckBox2" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>
                       <span disabled="disabled"><input id="ctl00_icerik_GridView4_ctl07_CheckBox3" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$icerik$GridView4$ctl07$CheckBox3" disabled="disabled" /></span>
                       </td><td>asasd@dwd.com</td><td>18.1.2013 14:31:03</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
        </span>
        </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>


       </div>


    <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
    <div id="site_info">
        <p>
            <a href="#">Kontrol Bilgi Sistemleri</a>. Tüm Hakları Saklıdır.
        </p>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No it is not related visibility. It does not change anything

Comment: please post your code behind code

Comment: behind code is too long and there is nothing related with checkbox visibility

Comment: What about your stylesheet?

Comment: Use `ClientIdMode=Predictable` for the checkboxes in the template fields.

Comment: @mshsayem thank you but it does not solve the problem. Simon there is nothing about checkbox in my stylesheet.

Comment: Please show us the generated HTML (from the browser's *view source*)

Comment: @Blachshma I add generated Html Code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try removing these lines: `$('input[type="checkbox"]').fancybutton();`
and `$('input[type="radio"]').fancybutton();`. Also, I recommend creating a new page, without all the styles and logic, only with the gridview, and see if it works there.

Comment: I delete two line that you have said. It works thank you so much.